# Concurrency control Oracle with Delphi7

Tags: c#, oracle, delphi, oracle9i

We are facing issue to access Oracle rows in incremental manner, The table schema is-

```
myTable(UniqueNum,flag)
```

UniqueNum is a field where number does not repeat and flag is the field which has default value as F.

My steps in programming are:

1. Fetch UniqueNum where flag is F.

   ```
   select min(UniquaNum) 
     from myTable 
    where flag='F';
   ```
2. Perform operation.

Some operations(Communication on comport)

3. Set flag as T.

   ```
   Update myTable 
      set flag='T' 
    where flag='F' 
      and UniqueNum= 'UN'
   ```

I developed an exe (Delphi-7) which is performing these steps. The problem occurs when the exe runs on more than one PC simultaneously. Many exe fetch the same UniqueNum (step-1) but only one of those exe can execute all 3 steps.

Let's say, PC1 selects `13` and performing step 2, and at that time PC2 executes STEP 1 then it will also fetch `13`. Then My step 3 will be failed for PC2.

What I want to know, whether there is some mechanism to avoid such type of fetching (Row lock or table lock)?

Can anyone suggest the better solution to avoid such concurrency? How can one implement the same in Delphi or C#?

Comment: Where is the sample of code for those steps: 1, 2, 3? And what exactly is the problem? Others are locked? `to avoid such type of fetching` what type of fetching exactly? What version of oracle you are using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 9i, also the steps are-
Step1 select min(UniquaNum) from myTable where flag='F';
Step 2- Some operations(Communication on comport)
Step3 - Update myTable set flag='T' where flag='F' and UniqueNum= 'UN'
lets say, PC1 selects 13 and performing step 2, and at that time PC2 executes step1 then it will also fetch 13. then My step3 will be failed for PC2.

Comment: `will be failed for PC2` define failed. Is it locked(I assume it would if your first session didn't commit  after step 3) or an error's shown?

Comment: You could create a Store Procedure that will return the value for the unique number. It seems like that is where you logic should be.Make sure you set the flag to another state as soon as you're done fetching as to avoid other requests returning the same value.

Answer (score 1):

In step 1 you'd want to do a "select .. for update nowait".  You'll have to check if the query succeeded and act accordingly.

Comment: Also as a general rule you'll want to only select records that you are actually going to change and keep the transaction as short as possible.

Comment: `transaction as short as possible`  In Oracle the length of a transaction should be as long as it needs to be - as long as business rule requires it to be and no shorter and no longer. Oracle isn't SQL Server where you have to commit as soon as possible to deal with locking issues.

Comment: ^ So does SQL Server. The transaction should be no shorter nor longer than it must be.

Comment: Let me change from saying this is terrible advice (because it doesn't actually block) but it still prevents other PC's from making any progress. Because now they're unable to complete step 1 successfully. So the process is effectively serialised across steps 1-3; with the problem just punted back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

As you didn't say what failed mean I can only assume that either row is the second session has to wait or step 2 fails processing because your query in more than one session return same minimum number. If you were on 11g and up you could take advantage of using `for update skip locked` clause. But you are on 9i so you have to emulate this. Here is one way:

Since `UniqueNum` as you said (`UniqueNum is a field where number does not repeat` is a field where number does not repeat) contains unique values we do not have to actually use `min()` function, we can `order by`  `UniqueNum`.

Here function `next_min_number` will replace your `select min() from` query. what it does is it tries to lock first (row with min `uniquenum`) and if row is already locked it tries to lock next one. As soon as it succeeds it'll return value of `UniqueNum`.

```
create or replace function next_min_number 
 return number
 is
   l_res number;
   row_locked exception;
   pragma exception_init(row_locked, -54);
 begin
    for i in (select un
                from t1
               where flag = 'F' /*of course this value can be passed as parameter */
               order by un ) 
    loop
      begin
        -- trying to lock the row
        select un
          into l_res
          from t1
         where un = i.un
         for update nowait;
         /*row of interest is locked, exit the loop*/
         exit;
       exception 
         when row_locked then null;
         when no_data_found then null;         
       end;     
    end loop;
    return l_res;
 end;
```

Note: Depending on how many records with `F` in the `Flag` column you have
      indexing only records where `Flag` is `F` would be a good idea.

Note 2: If either of the columns can contain `NULL' you have to deal with it accordingly.

Test case:

Set up:

```
create table t1(
  un number,
  flag varchar2(1)
);

insert into t1
  select level
       , 'F'
    from dual
   connect by level <= 3;

 commit;

select *
  from t1

       UN FLAG
---------- ----
         1 F   
         2 F   
         3 F
```

Session #1:

```
 set serveroutput on;
 var min_num number;
 -- your program
 begin
     :min_num := next_min_number;
     dbms_output.put_line('Current min number: ' || to_char(:min_num));
     dbms_output.put_line('Updating...');
    end;
  /
Current min number: 1                                                           
Updating...                                                                     
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Session #2

```
set serveroutput on;
var min_num number;
 -- your program
begin
    :min_num := next_min_number;
    dbms_output.put_line('Current min number: ' || to_char(:min_num));
    dbms_output.put_line('Updating...');
  end;
 /
Current min number: 2                                                           
Updating...                                                                     
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

As we can see both sessions running concurrently got different numbers.

Then each session issues updates.

session #1

```
 update t1
    set flag = 'T'
  where flag = 'F'
    and un = :min_num;

1 row updated.

commit;
```

session #2

```
 update t1
    set flag = 'T'
  where flag = 'F'
    and un = :min_num;

1 row updated.

commit;
```

Result:

```
select *
  from t1;

        UN FLAG
---------- ----
         1 T   
         2 T   
         3 F   

3 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

the Oracle way is to use a sequence.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
 START WITH     1000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

SELECT customers_seq.nextval from DUAL;
```

This is the only way I know for a stable version over more than 1 clients. This Select will give a new number every time you ask for it.

Of course you could encapsulate this into a function

```
function GiveNextID():integer;
```

or anythin like that.

As far as I remember you could put it into the table definition as Default value for a column.